# Using pure Javascript to show contents of list on click only on mobile and show initially on desktop

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there way I can make a list item to show initially only on desktop and when changing the screen size, the list item is dynamically changed to a dropdown-ish thing, where you have to **click** the `clickable heading` to show the contents of it? I want to use **pure JS** for it.

```
    <h2 class="clickable-heading">Toggle This Dropdown</h2>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#">How To Do This</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Installing in The Mid 90s</a>

    </li>
</ul>

<h2 class="clickable-heading">Click This Dropdown 2</h2>
```

JS:

```
function toggleDocs(event) {

if (event.target && event.target.className == 'clickable-heading') {

    var next = event.target.nextElementSibling;


    if (next.style.display == "none") {
        next.style.display = "block";

    } else {
        next.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

document.addEventListener('click', toggleDocs, true);
```

This is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1BJK903/af9qvkmp/).

PS: I know it's possible with `CSS`, using the **checkbox hack**, but I want to avoid that.

Comment: You can probably use css media queries to change the display of the list items according to screensize.

Comment: True, but I want to have a clickable heading. I can't do that with CSS, without using the checkbox hack. I want to avoid that.

Comment: Modify class names, not style properties. Then use media queries in your CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` to get the window dimensions.

And then depending on these dimensions show/hide the `li` elements, if you hide them bind the click event to the clickable `h2`, this is the working code:

```js
function toggleDocs() {
  var next = this.nextElementSibling;
  if (next.style.display == "none") {
    next.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    next.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function checkWindowDimensions() {
  var winWidth = window.innerWidth;
  var winHeight = window.innerHeight;
  console.log(winWidth + " ::: " + winHeight);

  var ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
  
  if (winWidth < 300 || winHeight < 300) {
    
      ul.style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementsByClassName("clickable-heading")[0].addEventListener('click', toggleDocs, true);
  } else {
    document.getElementsByClassName("clickable-heading")[0].removeEventListener('click', toggleDocs, true);
    if (ul.nodeType == 1)
      ul.style.display = 'block';
  }
}

checkWindowDimensions();

window.onresize = function(event) {
   checkWindowDimensions();
};
```

```css
ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="clickable-heading">Toggle This Dropdown</h2>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#">How To Do This</a>

  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Installing in The Mid 90s</a>

  </li>
</ul>

<h2 class="clickable-heading">Click This Dropdown 2</h2>
```

This is the **[updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chsdk/af9qvkmp/4/)**.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't get it to work when change screen size and clicking the title?

Comment: Make sure the width of the screen is lower than 300px like in the example.

Comment: Sorry, my bad I missed a little think, I edited the code, you have to bind the clck directly with the given h2 element and not with the document.

Comment: @Siyah yes if the list is not hidden you can't click, but if it's (the width or the height are lower than 300 px) you will be able to click, I don't know why it works from the second click.

Comment: I have hidden the ul, but can't click on the title when the width or height are lower than 300px. It just does nothing when clicked. Tested in Firefox / JsFiddle / CodePen and everything.

Comment: please add a codePen link so we can test it?  
I tetsed it in FuireFox and Chrome and works, but like I said from the second click.

Comment: I've clicked like 20 times, still nothing. Besides, you can check it by clicking on "run snippet" here as well. Make your screen fullsize and voila: the title is clickable, while it is larger than 300px (or higher)... Codepen btw: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJNOrP

Comment: @Siyah you have to attach the function to window.onresize event, see my EDited Answer, and run the snippet, and it works from the first click.

Comment: I think we are close... The "run snippet" area does not work; it just makes it always clickable. And for your code: it doesn't work when resizing my browser. It isn't clickable at all now.

Comment: @Siyah yes you are right, I was just editing it, you have to remove the evnet handler onclick if you resize, I added `document.getElementsByClassName("clickable-heading")[0].removeEventListener('click', toggleDocs, true);`, and it works as Expected.